# How to increment ID field stored within a string in excel using JAVA

Tags: java, json, excel, api, rest

I have particular scenario where I will be storing JSON in excel cell.
for example

`{A="AAA",B="BBB",ID="123", C="CCC",D="DDD"....}`

is stored in excel

Now for each execution I want `ID` field to be different(mostly unique). So here I can generate ID using `random number generation` function or I can store some ID in different excel sheet and read it from there.

Does anyone have idea how can we achieve it?

Comment: Your ID must be a number or the only thing that matter for you is the fact that it is unique?

Comment: ID should be number(integer) that will solve my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

I could not found the exact solution but I got work around solution.

Let's say I want final string as :

String finalVariable = {A="AAA",B="BBB",ID="123", C="CCC",D="DDD"....}

Then I am resonstructing it using

```
String finalVariable = var1+randomNumberGenerator+var2
```

where

```
  var1 = A="AAA",B="BBB",ID=";
  integer = generated using random number generation method;
  var2 = ", C="CCC",D="DDD";
```